# PostgreSQL subqueries as values

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to use a postgreSQL INSERT query with a subquery as parameter value. This is to find the corresponding user_id from an accompanying auth_token in user_info tabel first and then create a new entry in a different table with the corresponding user_id.

My query looks something like this

```
INSERT INTO user_movies(user_id, date, time, movie, rating)
VALUES ((SELECT user_id FROM user_info where auth_token = $1),$2,$3,$4,$5)
RETURNING *
```

I know that a query such as this will work with a single value

```
INSERT INTO user_movies(user_id)
SELECT user_id FROM user_info where auth_token = $1
RETURNING *
```

but how do I allow for multiples input values. Is this even possible in postgreSQL.

I am also using nodejs to run this query -> therefore the $ as placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment (it *is* probably a solution, IIUC): Easiest in this case would be to make the inner query return all the values.  So, assuming columns from the inner query have the right names, you could just

```sql
INSERT INTO user_movies(user_id, date, time, movie, rating)
SELECT user_id,$2,$3,$4,$5 FROM user_info where auth_token = $1
RETURNING *
```

Note this form is also *without* `VALUES`, it uses a query instead.

**Edited 20220424**: a_horse_with_no_name removed the useless brackets around `SELECT ...`   that appeared in my original version; *thanks!*

Comment: The parentheses around the SELECT are useless and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

YOu could try uising where IN clause

```
INSERT INTO user_movies(user_id)
SELECT user_id 
FROM user_info
WHERE auth_token IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)
RETURNING *
```

Comment: Consider adding columns to the inner query:
`SELECT user_id,$2,$3,$4,$5 FROM user_info where auth_token = $1`.